# How to install imagingft in OSX and Ubuntu?

Tags: python, macos, ubuntu, python-imaging-library

I'm using PIL 1.1.6 to render a truetype font on my local Windows machine.  I'd like to be able to get the application running in OSX and Ubuntu (server).  So far the instructions I've found all deal with specific ports repositories on OSX (Darwinports, Macports, etc.) or very outdated instructions for Linux.

Has anyone *recently* got imagingft to work in either and what were your specific steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long ago I'd switched my OSX (Snow Leopard) python version from the default 2.6 back to 2.5 for compatibility reasons on a project I had been working on.  I switched it back to 2.6 and was then able to compile imagingft normally:

```
./configure
make
make install
```

I was able to do the same thing on my Ubuntu server and neither required that I even reinstall PIL, despite some sets of instructions stating that I might have to.